# Do GNUmakefile, GNUmakefile.am, and GNUmakefile.in indicate that Automake has been used?

Tags: linux, make, xenomai, automake

[The source folder of rtnet contains only the above mentioned files for compilation purposes.](http://www.xenomai.org/index.php/RTnet%3aMain#Source_Folder) Remaining files are the source code of the examples.

Question is that do these files indicate that they have been generated through automake?

If yes, then where should I look to find out what settings where made to configure automake for generating these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presence of the `.am` files indicates the project is intended to be used with AutoMake. They are the source files for AutoMake, and the only ‘configuration’ files needed if you're building a project.

Read through `GNUMakefile.am` to see how AutoMake is configured. Generally speaking, you don't need to do that in many cases. The standard `./configure; make; make install` and its variants works well.

The [GNU Build Toolchain, aka `autotools`, (check out the flowchart)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system#Tools_included_in_the_GNU_build_system) is *very* complex (and its use of [M4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) is not for the faint of heart — and to think I once used that to make a website). Your best allies are the documentation. All the tools have manpages, but most of their documentation comes in `info` pages (say `info automake`, or use your favourite info browser).

Have a look at [a tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html) for autotools or go browse the [official automake documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/).

Answer (score 0):

The settings for AutoMake are in the *.am files. IIRC those (can) generate the *.in files which are the templates used by ./configure to produce the effective files.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but: `IIRC those (can) generate the *.in files which are the templates used by ./configure to produce the effective files.` Didn't understand this very clearly. Moreover, can I too write a auutomake for a small hello world program for rtnet like they have done?